# What should I use instead of get_blog_option?

Tags: plugin-development, options

I am using a plugin that was using [`get_blog_option`](https://codex.wordpress.org/WPMU_Functions/get_blog_option) and it no longer works. I looked up the call and it doesn't work because it's a [wpmu function](https://codex.wordpress.org/WPMU_Functions/get_blog_option) only.

Is there an equivalent method that I can use for a regular non-wpmu site?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`get_option()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_option/) instead. The [`get_option()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_option/) method returns an option for the current blog.

In single site installation, the current blog is the only blog. So get [`get_option()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_option/) returns the option for it.